# Has anyone used Amazon CloudFront with Magento for serving static files?

Tags: magento-1.8, extensions

If so could you recommend any extensions ?

Comment: Please be more specific as to what you want to achieve with this.

Comment: this is a good tutorial, http://www.aschroder.com/2011/05/magento-and-amazons-cloudfront-cdn-the-easy-way/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need extensions, it is the same as all the other CDN providers such as MaxCDN. You just need to point to your account in admin and set your hosting up to point to the origins, which is your skin, js & media folders individually as subdomains, do not do the root otherwise your entire site will be available statically and that is not good for SEO.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I just stumble across a couple of developers who have been using cloud front for international stores and was unsure about how to set this up.

Comment: Correct, as long as the CDN supports origin fetch - which means content doesn't have to be uploaded, thus no extensions required. The content is fetched by the CDN from your server via HTTP then caches the content.